# Как добавить язык к виджету vova07\fileapi\Widget

Tags: yii2

На проекте используется плагин для загрузки картинок, в вендоре в конфиге указаны такие языки ['de', 'en', 'it', 'pl', 'pt-BR', 'ru'],
т.к. нет нужного языка (uk_UA) то, в логах постоянно вываливается ошибка:/

The message file for category 'vova07/fileapi' does not exist: /vendor/vova07/yii2-fileapi-widget/messages/uk-UA/fileapi.php Fallback file does not exist as well: /vendor/vova07/yii2-fileapi-widget/messages/uk/fileapi.php

Подскажите как добавить язык?

Answer (score 1):

В репозитории **vova07\fileapi\Widget** в директории с языковыми файлами отсутствует файл
**uk-UA/fileapi.php**. Если вы скачали расширение zip-архивом и перенесли в ваш проект, то можете добавить директорию **uk-UA/fileapi.php** с вашим языковым файлом прямо в папку с расширением. Если вы используете composer, то создайте в вашем проекте файл **uk-UA/fileapi.php** и напишите перевод на вашем языке

```
return [
    'ERROR_CAN_NOT_UPLOAD_FILE' => 'Файл не может быть загружен',
    'MODAL_CANCEL' => 'Отмена',
    'MODAL_SAVE' => 'Загрузить',
    'MODAL_TITLE' => 'Кроп изображения',
    'BROWSER_DOESNT_SUPPORT_DRAG_AND_DROP' => 'Браузер не поддерживает "Drag & Drop"',
    'BROWSE_BTN' => 'Выбрать',
    'DRAG_AND_DROP' => 'Drag & Drop',
];
```

Затем создайте класс-наследник от виджета **yii2-fileapi-widget/Widget.php** и переопределите метод **registerTranslations**

```
/**
     * Register widget translations.
     */
    public function registerTranslations()
    {
        if (!isset(Yii::$app->i18n->translations['vova07/fileapi']) && !isset(Yii::$app->i18n->translations['vova07/*'])) {
            Yii::$app->i18n->translations['vova07/fileapi'] = [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'basePath' => '@app/messages/fileapi', //сюда положите директорию с языковым файлом
                'fileMap' => [
                    'vova07/fileapi' => 'fileapi.php'
                ],
                'forceTranslation' => true
        ];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно!

Comment: @ProMix если ответ помог, отметьте его решением